# How do I change location of email address in elsarticle?

Tags: elsarticle

Here is what my sample code looks like --

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@pprintTitle{%
    \let\@oddhead\@empty
    \let\@evenhead\@empty
    \let\@evenfoot\@empty
    \let\@oddfoot\@empty
}
\makeatother


\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin = 1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frontmatter}
        
        \title{The title of the article}
        
        \author[mainaddress]{Author 1}
        
        \author[mainaddress]{Author 2}
        \ead{email@server.com}
        
        \address[mainaddress]{The Green Earth}
        
        \begin{abstract}
            \lipsum[1]
        \end{abstract}
        
        \begin{keyword}
            kw1 \sep kw2
        \end{keyword}
        
    \end{frontmatter}
    
    \section{Introduction}
    \lipsum[2-3]
\end{document}
```

This is the output of this sample code --
[image: sample code output]

How do I move the email address to the location marked in red?

Comment: If this is for an article submission, why do you want to change it?

Comment: @Werner I am not submitting to Elsevier journals. The other publisher doesn't want footnotes but its own latex template is incompatible with amsmath.

Answer (score 1):

The following code uses [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to patch `\pprintMaketitle` - the macro responsible for printing the title. It inserts the printing of an email address just before the `\hrule` of the abstract.

[image]

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\pprintMaketitle}% <cmd>
  {\hrule}% <search>
  {\makebox[\linewidth][l]{\itshape Email address: \upshape who@cares.com}%
   \par
   \vspace{.5\baselineskip}% Space between email address and following rule
   \hrule}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  
\begin{frontmatter}

\title{The title of the article}

\author[mainaddress]{Author 1}

\author[mainaddress]{Author 2}
%\ead{email@server.com}

\address[mainaddress]{The Green Earth}

\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
  kw1 \sep kw2
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}
  
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-3]

\end{document}
```

Other adjustments can be made as needed.